# Does PHP sequentially process includes

Tags: php

I have separate php files that I have running on my linux server in separate cron jobs. I'd like to consolidate them into one cron job that calls a single php file with multiple php includes, and run them sequentially. Each include must wait to process until the prior is completed. Is this the behavior of how php processing of server-side includes occurs (note: there is no html involved here)? If not, is there a suggested alternative?

Comment: Yes, yes it does...

Comment: yes, php is a procedural language and processes code in the order it was written.

Comment: php isn't threaded. `include` (and pretty much any other function/call in php) will block until it's completed.

Comment: Easily testable, no?

Comment: Thanks, all for your quick replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you include them one after one, like this:

```
include 'a.php';
include 'b.php';
include 'c.php';
```

...then yes, `b.php` won't start until `a.php` hasn't completely finished its job
This is just how PHP works - line after line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  A class/file upon which another class/file is dependent should be included (or required) before the dependent class/file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the next include will not run unless the previous execution is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is yes, includes execute sequentially so long as nothing you're executing in those includes creates a new process on the server or calls another program that generates it's own process.

Answer (score 0):

A way to make includes managable, you could convert all includes into functions and then proceed like this:

```
Include a.php.  //contains function definitions
Include b.php.  //contains function definitions
Include c.php.  //contains function definitions
functionFromC();
functionFromA();
functionFromB();
```

But I don't know if that fits your needs.  ;-)